# BeautifulSoup for job searching

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to search jobs in my field in batch mode with the use of `BeautifulSoup`. I would have a list of urls, all consisting of employer career pages. If the search finds the keyword `GIS` in the job title, I want it to return the link to the job posting.

I'll give some case scenarios:

The first company site required a keyword search. This page is the result:

`https://jobs-challp.icims.com/jobs/search?ss=1&searchKeyword=gis&searchCategory=&searchLocation=&latitude=&longitude=&searchZip=&searchRadius=20`

I would like it to return the following:

`https://jobs-challp.icims.com/jobs/2432/gis-specialist/job`

`https://jobs-challp.icims.com/jobs/2369/gis-specialist/job`

The second site did not require a keyword search:

`https://www.smartrecruiters.com/SpectraForce1/`

I would like it to return the following:

`https://www.smartrecruiters.com/SpectraForce1/74966857-gis-specialist`

`https://www.smartrecruiters.com/SpectraForce1/74944180-gis-technician`

This is as far as I can get:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = 'https://www.smartrecruiters.com/SpectraForce1/'
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

text = soup.get_text()

if 'GIS ' in text:
        print 'Job Found!'
```

There are two problems:
1.) This of course returns a confirmation that a job is found, but does not return the link to the job itself
2.) The two relevant positions were not found using this method for the first company site. I checked this by scanning the output of `soup.get_text()`, and saw that it did not contain job titles in the returned text.

Any help or additional suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a go!

This code will find all *links* with the string containing 'GIS'. I needed to add `&in_iframe=1` to make the first link work.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['https://jobs-challp.icims.com/jobs/search?ss=1&searchKeyword=gis&searchCategory=&searchLocation=&latitude=&longitude=&searchZip=&searchRadius=20&in_iframe=1',
        'https://www.smartrecruiters.com/SpectraForce1/']

for url in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
    print 'Scraping {}'.format(url)
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        if 'GIS' in link.text:
            print '--> TEXT: ' + link.text.strip()
            print '--> URL:  ' + link['href']
            print ''
```

Output:

```
Scraping https://jobs-challp.icims.com/jobs/search?ss=1&searchKeyword=gis&searchCategory=&searchLocation=&latitude=&longitude=&searchZip=&searchRadius=20&in_iframe=1
--> TEXT: GIS Specialist
--> URL:  https://jobs-challp.icims.com/jobs/2432/gis-specialist/job?in_iframe=1

--> TEXT: GIS Specialist
--> URL:  https://jobs-challp.icims.com/jobs/2369/gis-specialist/job?in_iframe=1

Scraping https://www.smartrecruiters.com/SpectraForce1/
--> TEXT: Technical Specialist/ Research Analyst/ GIS/ Engineering Technician
--> URL:  https://www.smartrecruiters.com/SpectraForce1/74985505-technical-specialist

--> TEXT: GIS Specialist
--> URL:  https://www.smartrecruiters.com/SpectraForce1/74966857-gis-specialist

--> TEXT: GIS Technician
--> URL:  https://www.smartrecruiters.com/SpectraForce1/74944180-gis-technician
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Amazing that this little module can do. Thanks so much Steinar Lima!

Comment: No problem :) BeautifulSoup is a nice tool, you should look into it!

Answer (score 1):

here is one way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

url = 'https://www.smartrecruiters.com/SpectraForce1/'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

titles = [i.get_text() for i in soup.findAll('a', {'target':'_blank'})]
jobs = [re.sub('\s+',' ',title) for title in titles]

links = [i.get('href') for i in soup.findAll('a', {'target':'_blank'})]

for i,j in enumerate(jobs):
    if 'GIS' in j:
        print links[i]
```

if you run this right now it will print:

```
https://www.smartrecruiters.com/SpectraForce1/74985505-technical-specialist
https://www.smartrecruiters.com/SpectraForce1/74966857-gis-specialist
https://www.smartrecruiters.com/SpectraForce1/74944180-gis-technician
```

Comment: Thank you Christian Careaga. I've accepted the other answer, because it resolved both issues, but yours works nicely. Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt, but it's pretty much the same as above :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

def work(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read())

    for i in soup.findAll("a", text=True):
        if "GIS" in i.text:
            print "Found link "+i["href"].replace("?in_iframe=1", "")

urls = ["https://jobs-challp.icims.com/jobs/search?pr=0&searchKeyword=gis&searchRadius=20&in_iframe=1", "https://www.smartrecruiters.com/SpectraForce1/"]

for i in urls:
    work(i)
```

It defines a function "work()" that does the actual work, getting the page from the remote server; using `urlopen()` since it looked like you wanted to use `urllib2` but I suggest you use [Python-Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/); then it finds all `a` elements (links) using `findAll()`, and for each link it checks if "GIS" is in the link's text, and if it is then it prints the link's `href` attribute.

Then it defines the list of URLs (just 2 URLs in this case) using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), and then it runs the `work()` function for each URL in the list and passes it as an argument to the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot André! Out of curiosity, do you have any idea why it can't locate GIS on this page? It's page 4 of the Job Listings, but it seems to go to Page 1 (I know this because it can locate Archaeologist, but not GIS - https://re12.ultipro.com/CARDNO/JobBoard/listjobs.aspx?Page=Browse&__SVRTRID=023C377A-1F7C-425B-B2F1-8FA2AA1F1B58

Comment: That page uses some nasty and complicated way of loading next page data, a click on the "next page" button triggers a POST request with lots of stuff including a CSRF token and some other data, so it's gonna be complicated to scrape that page (you'll need to read the CSRF token and redo that complicated POST request from Python).

Comment: @André You don't have to call `read()` on urlopen when passing it to BS.